# How can we add condition for targetClass in AnyMetaDef?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hql, any

When a value is deleted from the table, I do not delete that value from the database; I just change the status column value to 'DELETED'. I prevent deleted values ​​from returning with the `@Where(clause = "status != 'DELETED'")` condition at the beginning of each `Entity(Book,VHS,DVD)` class.

```
 @Entity
 @Where(clause = "status != 'DELETED'")
 public class Book ....
```

However;

```
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE"),fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", 
            metaValues = { 
             @MetaValue(targetEntity = Book.class, value = "B"),
             @MetaValue(targetEntity = VHS.class, value = "V"),
             @MetaValue(targetEntity = DVD.class, value = "D")
       })
    @JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Object item;
```

If I use the this code block, it also pulls the DELETED values. I think when we do `targetEntity = Book.class`, it does not see the `@Where` condition written in `BookEntity`.

How can I add the Where run here or how do I prevent withdrawals of 'DELETED' status here?

Comment: put the `@Where` on the `private Object item;`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I tried it, but I can't access the status value in the targetEntity classes in Where. I said where (clause = "ITEM_TYPE.status!='DELETED'") but it didn't work.